# Set Color to Variable for later use in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

i try to store a Color to a variable that i can use later without providing RGB informations twice:

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Color Color1 = new Color();
    public Color Color2 = new Color();

    public Form1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        Color1 = Color.White;
        Color2 = Color.FromArgb(255, 112, 114);
    }


    private void LoadSomething()
    {
    //not working - but dont know why
    TreeNode TreeNode1 = new TreeNode();
    TreeNode1.ForeColor = Color1;
    TreeNode1.BackColor = Color2;

    //working
    TreeNode TreeNode1 = new TreeNode();
    TreeNode1.ForeColor = Color.White;
    TreeNode1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 112, 114);
    }

}
```

Can someone tell me why its not working in the first way? thx

Comment: Because you're doing something differently to what you're showing us.

Comment: Yeeah, this is really simple code that has no reason not to work. Unless `LoadSomething` is somehow called by some listener that is triggered during `InitializeComponents`. That would do it, since the colours aren't assigned yet at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason could be as follows:

You call your method befor constructor of `Form1` is called. This way, color objects are instantiated, but in constructor you pass object with actual colors specified. Thus, before constructor is called, you have "blank" colors, after constructor is called, you have white and the other color.

So, if you call `LoadSomething` before constructor is called, the first approach won't work. The second, directly specifies color, so it will always work.

But to be sure, you should share code, where you call `LoadSomething`.

Comment: you are absolutely right, i checked it, and accidentely loaded LoadSomething in the constructor before setting the colors. thx

Comment: @Patric You could just assign the correct colours right there in `public Color Color1 = ` instead of calling that useless `new Color()` constructor.